# OneNote API fails to get any notes from shared notebook for sharing user

Tags: php, onenote, onenote-api

As the developer, I'm able to GET (using PHP via the REST API) all notes from a notebook shared with a client. As you see, a search by me returns all 25 notes within the accessed section:

> {
>     "@odata.context":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#me/notes/sections('0-240BD74C83900C17%21128584')/pages(title,id,links,contentUrl)","@odata.count":25,"value":[
>       {
>       ...

But logged in as my (duly authenticated) client (and using exactly the same code), we get 0 notes:

> {
>     "@odata.context":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#me/notes/sections('0-240BD74C83900C17%21128584')/pages(title,id,links,contentUrl)","@odata.count":0,"value":[
>     ]
>   }

What needs to be done for my client to get not just the section in the shared notebook but (more importantly!) the notes in that section?

Answer (score 1):

First off apologies for the shared pages not being returned by the API. I've tracked the issue down to a regional incident in our partner service. (user impact is estimated to be <1% of the total active users).

Once the incident is resolved, you will see the shared pages being returned correctly.

In the meantime, as a **temporary workaround** adding the below header to your API request will return the shared pages.

FavorDataRecency: true

Comment: Many thanks for your prompt investigation of this issue, Dipak. I'll try the workaround and look forward to the permanent resolution.

Comment: Wow! With the workaround, my client now gets all pages - big sighs of relief all round! Having spent a day going over all my code with a fine tooth-comb, I'm vastly relieved that the issue is an external one :) Thanks again, Dipak, for your work in tracking the problem down to its source.

Comment: For future readers, this ***temporary workaround*** should no longer be needed (since the regional incident was resolved). Use this header with caution since it introduces a much higher perf hit.

Comment: I can confirm that this issue is now fully resolved and that I've been able to revert the temporary workaround. Thanks Dipak for your prompt and effective attention to this issue.

Comment: Note: FavorDataRecency is no longer supported.

Comment: Does this even work for Onenote business account. Since when I try to get all pages including the shared once with me. It doesn't seems to work for business account